# how to put an arraylist into a combobox in java?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist, combobox

my code

```
 for (Customer cusList1 : cusList) {
            int numAcc = cusList1.getAccNo();
            for (int c = 0; c<cusList.size(); c++) {
                String arr [] = new String [numAcc];
                arr[c] = cusList1.getName();
                DefaultComboBoxModel RefCMB1 = new DefaultComboBoxModel(arr); //Assign Model data to ComboBoxes from Array
                newNameCombo.setModel(RefCMB1);
            }
    }
```

I have Customer details in an arraylist an i want to put the names onto a combobox.
cusList is the name of the ArrayList. newNameCombo is the name of the combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a Vector instead for convenience, though it is considered as a bit obsolete. 
btw do you store the names in an

```
ArrayList<String>
```

or an

```
ArrayList<Customer>
```

? For the former one you may try:

```
ArrayList<String> list = ...
JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(new Vector<>(list));
```

, or use a Vector from the very first if you don't mind.
I would prefer generics. Indeed, using an array to build a JComboBox is also valid.

For the latter one you may want to work on a DefaultListCellRenderer. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.html). Override   getListCellRendererComponent() to add Customer into your JComboBox and render it by yourself. (This is the more desirable way as you can set and retrieve Customer directly.)

edit: according to your code, I suggest this:

```
JComboBox<Customer> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(new Vector<>(cusList));
comboBox.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel)super.getListCellRendererComponent(list,value,index,isSelected,cellHasFocus);
        label.setText(((Customer)value).getName());
        return label;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not fill a DefaultComboBoxModel with a ArrayList.

You need to convert the list to an array or vector and pass to the constructor.

```
JComboBox cmb_box = new JComboBox(cusList.toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.util.Vector instead of ArrayList. Vector is generally a synchronized (thread-safe) ArrayList, it also implements List interface. Furthermore, changes made to the Vector will be visible in the JComboBox.

```
Vector<String> data = new Vector<>();
data.add("a");
data.add("b");
JComboBox<String> jComboBox = new JComboBox<>(data);
data.add("c");
```